# write mysql query in bad way

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, pdo

Please look at my PHP code:

**PHP:**

```
$username = 'kia';
$pswd = 'kiakia';
$db = 'jahaad';

$kaan = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname = jahaad', $username, $pswd);

if ($kaan) { echo 'Connected<br />'; }

else { echo 'Not Connected'; }

$address = "../letters/Assistance01/office01/letter001.txt";

$open = fopen($address, 'r');

$size = filesize($address);

$file = fread($open, ($size*4));

fclose($open);

$filename = basename($address);

echo '<hr />' . $filename;

$type = strstr($filename, '.');

echo '<br /> ' . $type;

$recieveTime = date('Y/m/d H:m:s');

echo '<br />' . $recieveTime;

$from = 'test';

$sql = 'INSERT (`filename`, `filetype`, `recieve`, `from`, `file`) INTO `jahaad`.`assis01_office01` VALUES(:filename, :filetype, :recieve, :from, :file)';

$result = $kaan->prepare($sql);

$result->execute(array(':filename'=>$filename, ':filetype'=>$type, ':recieve'=>$recieveTime, ':from'=>$from, ':file'=>$file));
if ($result) {
    echo '<br />OK';
}
else {
    echo '<br />Problem';   
}
```

except the file column, every column type is VARCHAR in my Database.
when I run the code, `$result` is true!!! but nothing is added to my DB...
Would you tell me what is wrong???

**Edit:**
It's Because of my careless in writing the Query...
hope You don't do this...

Comment: I believe the syntax for inserting into a MySQL database is `INSERT INTO table (column1,column2) VALUES ('col1val','col2val')`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18120759/2864740 (and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) - then follow the advice to see what the error(s) are. (I could tell you at least one thing that is wrong, but it's *more important* that other errors in the future can be detected/reported.)

Comment: _Please Don't vote me Dawn if You think this question is not useful_ - if a question isn't useful, it isn't useful, regardless of whether you're an amateur. Similarly, amateurs can post useful questions too.

Comment: YES... Thats it... Thanks alot...

Comment: may be a question for an amateur is useful but as a perfect programmer, you think this is funny or useless... it's about 3 hours I'm trying to understand this simple thing and may be it's very very simple for you, so your judgment is not true bro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with your PHP code, but a problem with your MySQL query.

This line

```
$sql = 'INSERT (`filename`, `filetype`, `recieve`, `from`, `file`) INTO `jahaad`.`assis01_office01` VALUES(:filename, :filetype, :recieve, :from, :file)';
```

Should be

```
$sql = 'INSERT  INTO `jahaad`.`assis01_office01` (`filename`, `filetype`, `recieve`, `from`, `file`) VALUES(:filename, :filetype, :recieve, :from, :file)';
```